# PageSpeed Insights for Global Scores

Tags: internationalization, global, pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

We are in the US and using PageSpeed Insights, but really wanting to know how our website performs for our Chinese (and other global customers).  We don't have a specific URL to pass in - localization is IP/cookie based.  Is there a solution that will allow us, via the API, to pull back metrics for other locations?